# How to make a checkbox check dynamically based on a array of values in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, angular6

My ajax call result is like the following,

```
data : 
  0: {Address: "Delhi", EmailID: "bravo123@gmail.com", MobileNo: 
"9876543210", Name: "Bravo", Date: "04/06/2008", …}
1: {Mode: "0"}
2: {Mode: "1"}
3: {Mode: "2"}
4: {Mode: "3"}
5: {Mode: "4"}
```

I can display the datas using,

```
 <p *ngIf="details">{{ details[0]?.EmailID }}</p>
```

But the modes which Im getting are the values of checkboxes. How can I make a checkbox selected based on the values which is returing from ajax call.

My checkbox code html is given following:

```
   <div class="custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input 
       [attr.id]="mode[i].id" [name]="mode[i].name"
       [checked]="(mode && (mode.indexOf(mode[i].id) !== -1))">
     <label class="custom-control-label" [attr.for]="mode[i].id"> 
       {{mode[i].name}}</label>
   </div>
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" 
       [attr.id]="mode[i+1].id" [name]="mode[i+1].name"
       [checked]="(mode && (mode.indexOf(mode[i+1].id) !== -1))">
     <label class="custom-control-label" [attr.for]="mode[i+1].id"> 
       {{mode[i+1].name}}</label>
   </div>
```

My ts file:

```
public mode = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Select All' },
  { id: 1, name: 'aaa' },
  { id: 2, name: 'bbb' },
  { id: 3, name: 'cccc' },
  { id: 4, name: 'dddd' },
];
```

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="item.id" [attr.checked]="fooData.mode === item.id ? true : null" />
```

notice **null** here.

I have created a small [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjw4zy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) like your code.

[**Updated Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjw4zy) with array of data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @SyedAliTaqi For single value, Im able to do. But if I have more values which are returning how can i check that checkbox? Will you please help me on that?

Comment: more values coming from service?

Comment: Yes Yes @SyedAliTaqi like it is returning three values aaa, bbb, ccc. How can i make them all selected?

Comment: can you change the example code in link and paste new link here?

Comment: Yes, but I need to check three values in a single row. In example we are having three rows knw?

Comment: right. please have a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjw4zy) now.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking fr. Thanks again